# How to make the default text in a select field grey like the placeholder for textfields?

Tags: sencha-touch

I have the following select field in a form:

```
        {
            xtype: 'selectfield',
            name: 'minprice',
            label: 'Min Price',
            valueField: 'No min',
            placeHolder: 'No min',
            useClearIcon: true,
            options: [{
                text: 'No Min', value: 'Test'
            }, {
                text: 'Test2', value: 'Test2'
            }, {
                text: 'Test3', value: 'Test3'
            }]                  
        }
```

I would like the first option 'No min' to look like a place holder (so it's light grey). The reason for this is that the rest of the form has placeholders in light grey and having a select field with black text doesn't fit the style of the form. I've tried specifying a placeholder and the the valueField with no success.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `placeHolder` property but then you shouldn't specify the `options` property. For example:

```
{ id:'theSelect',
  name: 'fieldId',
  xtype: 'selectfield',
  displayField: 'text',
  valueField: 'value',    
  placeHolder :'No min'
}
```

And then have this or load it from a store to load the options:

```
 Ext.getCmp('theSelect').setOptions(
[   {text: 'First Option',  value: 'first'},
    {text: 'Second Option', value: 'second'},
    {text: 'Third Option',  value: 'third'}
]);
```

See the whole working code here http://jsfiddle.net/p5K4q/16/

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with `-webkit-text-fill-color`.

The easiest way to target a specific field is like this:

```
{
    xtype: 'datepickerfield',
    placeHolder : 'Date',
    cls: 'your-class'
}

.your-class .x-form-field {
    -webkit-text-fill-color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `placeholder` and set the `AutoComplete` as `false`, since it is set to true by default..

This works fine for me.